# qt c++ how to delete and add widgets again

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to replace widgets based on combobox. I got two types in combobox, here is functions for that types:

```
void ThemeWidget::renderModeGraph() {
    clearMode();

    //create charts
    QChartView *chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->top_left_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->top_right_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->bottom_left_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->bottom_right_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;
}

void ThemeWidget::renderModeGraphStar() {
    clearMode();

    //create charts
    QChartView *chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->top_left_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->top_right_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->bottom_left_graph->addWidget(chartView);
    m_charts << chartView;

    chartView = new QChartView(createChart());
    m_ui->bottom_right_graph->addWidget(chartView);

    m_charts << chartView;
}
```

I call function `clearMode` between mode changing, here it is:

```
void ThemeWidget::clearMode() {
    if (!m_charts.isEmpty()) {
        m_ui->top_left_graph->removeWidget(m_charts[0]);
        m_ui->top_right_graph->removeWidget(m_charts[1]);
        m_ui->bottom_left_graph->removeWidget(m_charts[2]);
        m_ui->bottom_right_graph->removeWidget(m_charts[3]);
        m_charts.clear();
    }
}
```

At the start I call `renderModeGraph` and everything rendering, layout is good, everything is ok. But when I change mode layout structure is flow away. I  am new to qt and c++ so don't understand what is happen and how to fix that, please help or give advice to restructure layout.

Also here is layout structure and some screenshots.
[image: Ui layout structure]
[image: strating of programm]
[image: After choosing <code>graph *</code> in combobox]

Comment: Why do you have two identical functions at all?

Comment: Don't really see why you would drop the chart views all the time just to re-create them afterwards. Wouldn't it be more efficient just to [exchange](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html#setChart) the chart currently displayed?

Comment: oh, don't know that such function exists, thanks (ps they generated randomly so they are not the same) but what if I want to replace to not chart widget?

Comment: Then you might need to update the layout (it has an equally named function for). Possibly, you might want to select a more apropriate layout manager? I personally prefer creating the widgets just once, keeping them in parallel, and hide the ones that are not needed. [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) or [QStackedLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html) provide convenient means for.

Comment: thanks, I will look for them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a layout and that each time you remove a widget, the layout changes. So you need to fix it every time you change the widgets. To remove this problem you can create your base UI with a QWidget container that holds your chart widget. Every time you change your widgets, instead of deleting the QWidget container, your delete the chart and keep the QWidget. Then create your new widget and put it in the QWidget. That way your layout should stay the same.